# Perform click on button in one app from another app

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, onclicklistener

i want to perform click event in one application when device reboots from another app.
 I have an app installed in my device and i want to open that app when my device reboots and perform `onClick`  of button. I don't have source code of that application.

**Note:** For open that app i am using different app.

Comment: I think you can't do that

Answer (score 0):

**[System Permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html)**

> Android is a ***privilege-separated operating system***, in which each
>   application runs with a distinct system identity (**Linux user ID and
>   group ID**). Parts of the system are also separated into distinct
>   identities. **Linux thereby isolates applications from each other and
>   from the system.**

---

**Without root Access, you can't do this.**

Comment: so how to do it with root access?